# Set filter attribute to all controller methods using in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter

for example , I have:

```
ControllerA
{
  [MyFilterAttribute] 
  MethodA() 
  {
    return View("MyView");
  }
}
ControllerB
{

  MethodB() 
  {
    ...
    return Json(SomeData);
  }
}
```

In `MyView` I am using `MethodB` from `ControllerB` with Ajax request and I need `MyFilterAttribute`.

Is it possible to set `MyFilterAttribute` which is using in `ControllerA/MethodA` to return `MyView` for all methods used in `MyView` (from other controllers without attribute) without write this attribute before each method Or can find out that request is from view generated via method with this attribute?

So In this example:
Is it possible to set `MyFilterAttribute` which is using in `ControllerA` `MethodA` to return `MyView` for
`MethodB` which I used to get json?

Comment: At runtime or during build?

Comment: During build app.

Comment: You could generate your code or run a pre build script to add the attributes in the source code. I am not an expert on those scripts, thus I have no example. Or define a base class with the attribute.